# jQuery UI DatePicker read date from multiple fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have separate fields for month, day and year and have a calendar control for each set of three fields contained in a div. I am trying to have the calendar popup defaults to the date set in the fields if there is one and if no date set in the 3 fields it would default to todays like it currently does.

Here is my code.

HTML:

```
    <h1>Date Picker Example</h1>
<div class="date-picker">
 <label for="preferredDate">Date</label>
 <input type="text" class="date_month" value="06" size="2" maxlength="2" /> / 
 <input type="text" class="date_day" value="01" size="2" maxlength="2" /> / 
 <input type="text" class="date_year" value="2014" size="4" maxlength="4" />  
</div>
<div class="date-picker">
 <label for="preferredDate">Date</label>
 <input type="text" class="date_month" value="09" size="2" maxlength="2" /> / 
 <input type="text" class="date_day" value="09" size="2" maxlength="2" /> / 
 <input type="text" class="date_year" value="2017" size="4" maxlength="4" />   
</div>
<div class="date-picker">
 <label for="preferredDate">Date</label>
 <input type="text" class="date_month" size="2" maxlength="2" /> / 
 <input type="text" class="date_day" size="2" maxlength="2" /> / 
 <input type="text" class="date_year" size="4" maxlength="4" />  
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".date_year").datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    //buttonImage: "calendar_icon.png", 
    buttonText: 'Cal',
    buttonImageOnly: false,
    showAnim: 'fadeIn',
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    onClose: function (dateText, picker) {
        dateArr = dateText.split('/');
        $(this).siblings('.date_month').val(dateArr[0]);
        $(this).siblings('.date_day').val(dateArr[1]);
        $(this).val(dateArr[2]);
    }
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/C57Ws/3/

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Can you please describe the problem with what you have? What's wrong? What's not displaying? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Sorry. When you click on the calendar button the calendar is set to today's date and not the date in the fields. That is good if no date is input in the fields and are blank but if there is a date set already the calendar should popup showing that date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the datepicker option `beforeShow` to look at the inputs and create a datepicker object to set what ever you want.

I modified your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oumichaelm/C57Ws/6/)

Basically i just used the code you had in the `onClose` option. But went in reverse.

```
beforeShow: function (dateText, picker) {

    var month =     $(this).siblings('.date_month').val();
    var day = $(this).siblings('.date_day').val();
    var year = $(this).val();
    var showDate = day+ "/" + month + "/" + year;
    alert(showDate);
    // do some error checking before returning date to show.
    return { defaultDate: showDate };
},
```

I also change the code you were using in `onClose`.  If you notice your example, the datapicker is attached to the "year" input. If a user doesn't click a date (clicks outside datepicker) the `dateText` you are passing in will only have the year.  Your split method will not have a full date of three variables. That will result in the year getting added to the `date_month` if a date is not clicked on..

You can use `$(this).datepicker( "getDate" )` to make sure you get the date that was clicked, or empty string if nothing was clicked. It returns a Date object that you can use the standard date object methods.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the jQueryUI option [`defaultDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) or the jQueryUI method [`setDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) along with the jQueryUI option [`onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect).

I would suggest giving each set of date inputs (day, month, and year) a unique identifier. At the moment, you don't have anything to distinguish each set of dates by.

Comment: Since these are dynamic fields I am unable to use unique identifiers. The current code works but for the life of me i can not get it to read the field and default the calendar the default date if there is one already entered in the fields.